# BrightPattern API 401 error, adding a record with Java and JSON

Tags: java, json

So I'm not sure if many people have used the BrightPattern API, but what I need to do is be able to post a record using an HTTP Post and JSON.  Right now I'm posting to my url and I'm getting back a 401 error, when I'm looking for a 204.  I have credentials, and I know a 401 is an error that can mean that the credentials are incorrect, or that you need to sign in or something.  I'll show you guys my code and see if you guys can see my issue.

Also I really need this figured out so as soon as I can, I'll offer bounty as soon as I can for the correct answer.

```
public class GSONBrightPatternPost {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person personObj = new Person();
    personObj.setOrganization("ACC");
    personObj.setFirstName("Harry");
    personObj.setLastName("Smith");
    personObj.setPhone1(null);
    personObj.setPhone2(null);
    personObj.setEmail(null);
    personObj.setState("AZ");
    personObj.setLeadDate(null); // Fix Later
    personObj.setCompany("Bob's Mortage");
    personObj.setCompanyContactName("Indiana Jones");
    personObj.setOutsideRep("Joel Martin");

    Person personObj2 = new Person();
    personObj2.setOrganization("ACC");
    personObj2.setFirstName("Richard");
    personObj2.setLastName("Nixon");
    personObj2.setPhone1(null);
    personObj2.setPhone2(null);
    personObj2.setEmail(null);
    personObj2.setState(null);
    personObj2.setLeadDate(null); // Fix Later
    personObj2.setCompany("Bob's Mortage");
    personObj2.setCompanyContactName("Indiana Jones");
    personObj2.setOutsideRep("Joel Martin");

    List<Person> personArrayList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    personArrayList.add(personObj);
    personArrayList.add(personObj2);

    PersonList personList = new PersonList();
    personList.setPersonList(personArrayList);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    String json = gson.toJson(personList);

    try {
        // write converted json data to a file named "PersonList.json"
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Dylan\\JsonFiles\\PersonList.json");
        writer.write(json);
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try

    {


        SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
        builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build());
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                "https://***************.brightpattern.com:####/admin/ws/t/**************.brightpattern.com/callinglist/add/ListOldLeads");

        UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = 
                  new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
        postRequest.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, postRequest, null));

        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(json);
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (KeyStoreException e2) {

        e2.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e3) {

        e3.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (KeyManagementException e4) {

        e4.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (AuthenticationException e5) {

        e5.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
```

Also here's the documentation on how I'm supposed to submit this.  If anyone can find out what my issue is that would be so great.  Thanks in advance.

http://www.brightpattern.com/doc/Documentation/ServicePattern/3.10/list-management-api-specification/Addarecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, this is what I needed

```
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, 
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = 
            HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
```